# How to add array elements using a while loop in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to study for a final that I have tomorrow about arrays and calling them as functions and using while loops to add their elements. All of this is being done in C.

So, so far this is what I got:

first im defining the function so that the program knows it exists

```
    int sum(int[],int);


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {


        int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
            int x = sum(array,5);
}
```

And here is the function that I did:

```
    sum(int array[],int size){

        int countdown=0;
        int result= 0;

        while(countdown<size){

            printf("%d\n",array[countdown]);
            result= result + array[countdown];
            printf("%d",result);
            countdown++;

        }

       return 0;

    }
```

After compiling it and running it it runs alright, however it is not giving me the expected result of 15.

Comment: Did you mean to `return 0` in `sum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. Your results are not being seen very well.

Change

```
printf("%d\n",array[countdown]);
result= result + array[countdown];
printf("%d",result);
```

to

```
printf("Countdown %d\n",array[countdown]);
result = result + array[countdown];
printf("Result %d\n",result);
```

You will be able to see your result much clearer.

**Cleaned up code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int[],int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int x = sum(array,5);
    printf("Sum is: %d\n", x);
}

int sum(int array[],int size){
    int countdown=0;
    int result= 0;

    while(countdown<size){
        printf("Countdown %d\n",array[countdown]);
        result = result + array[countdown];
        printf("Result %d\n",result);
        countdown++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Results**

```
gcc test.c && ./a.out
Countdown 1
Result 1
Countdown 2
Result 3
Countdown 3
Result 6
Countdown 4
Result 10
Countdown 5
Result 15
Sum is: 15
```

Comment: Awesome. All the best with your finals!